# Write text to pipe and read result never completes

Tags: perl

I've written a Perl program that opens a pipe to `xargs` so that it will read from the input and run a command with each row of input.

I need to read the output from that pipe.

I use `open3` and then write the input to the input file handle. Then a loop reads from the output filehandle.

But when it prints the last line that I expect to see, it just hangs and doesn't complete the process.

Here's an excerpt from the script

```
my $classNamesOutput = `classNamesInArchive $opt_archive`;

my $pid = open3( \*CHILD_IN, \*CHILD_OUT, false, "xargs -n1 listJavaClassRefs -p $opt_archive -c" );
print "pid[" . $pid . "]\n";

print CHILD_IN $classNamesOutput;

my $output = '';
my $matchingArchiveNames = '';

while ( my $row = <CHILD_OUT> ) {
    chomp $row;
    print "row[" . $row . "]\n";

    if ( $onlyListingMatches == 1 && $row eq $opt_className ) {
        print $opt_archive;
        last;
    }

    if ( $onlyListingMatches == 0 ) {
        $output .= $row . "\n";
    }
}

print "Past loop.\n";
```

It never prints `Past loop`: it just hangs on the last line of output that I think the called script would have produced.

Comment: Does my edit represent your problem correctly? Please don't personalise everything.

Comment: Where did you get `open3` from? Do you `use` any modules that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Aside from the issue you asked about, your program suffers from a shell command injection bug. `"xargs -n1 listJavaClassRefs -p $opt_archive -c"` should be `"xargs", "-n1", "listJavaClassRefs", "-p", $opt_archive, "-c"`.

Comment: Aside from the issue you asked about, your program suffers from a race condition. Please avoid `open3` if you want bidirectional communication (cause you then need to start using IPC::Select too, and that gets really complicated). Instead, use IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run.

Comment: @Borodin I don't know what you mean by "personalize". I got open3 from cpan. Where else would I get it from?

Comment: @ikegami Please elaborate on these issues in answers.

Comment: Perhaps you need to familiarize yourself with [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)?

Comment: I'm well aware of the meanings of the terms.  Please explain why you believe this code is vulnerable to those issues.  I don't care about the potential injection issue, I might care about the possible race condition if you explained it.

Comment: @David: I mean talk about your code, not about yourself. *"In the main script, I'm attempting to use "open3" so I can specify both the input and output file handle"*

Comment: Re "*Please explain why you believe this code is vulnerable to those issues*", The race condition can lead to a deadlock (parent and child blocked writing to pipe). /// You are doing the very definition of code injection: You are inserting text into code (shell command) without first converting the text to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the writer before the while loop:

```
close CHILD_IN;
```

Edit: The reason you need to close the pipe for xargs (but not in general) is that xargs apparently does not launch any processes until the input in finished. This can be seen by running `cat | xargs echo`:

```
cat | xargs echo
asdf
asd
faw
seas
eryawr
yawr
ya
ryhs
rhy
erh
< I press Ctrl-d here to terminate pipe >
asdf asd faw seas eryawr yawr ya ryhs rhy erh
```

For non-xargs programs it might still be a good idea anyways to close the pipe, or at least flush it, since there might be bytes stuck in a buffer at some level.

Comment: Please elaborate on your advice